# How to extend storage to oracle ASMPROD database from HP EVA storage?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have in my company HPUNIX 2 servers and installed oracle 10g RAC database ,

Connected to HP storage command view EVA and I have available space on EVA storage 750 GB

I need to create new virtual disk and add more space to production database from EVA storage .

I have 2 questions :

1- when I create the virtual disk  it will show direct to production database and HPUX servers ?

2- when I create the new virtual disk it will not affect the current virtual disks and running database ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create new disk group and attach it to your database.

The answers to your questions :

1- when I create the virtual disk it will show direct to production database and HPUX servers ?

No need to create virtual disk just create new disk group and attach it to your ASMPROD disk but you need to check the EVA storage guide and oracle 10G database steps because its very old version.

2- when I create the new virtual disk it will not affect the current virtual disks and running database ?

If you create new disk group and attach it to your oracle database it will not affect the current and running database .

Comment: I will check with the DBA thank you